# Laravel 5.5 login with google got error Cannot use lexical variable $eventName as a parameter name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cannot use lexical variable $eventName as a parameter name
[image]

Comment: Also this is an issue with the version of guzzle you are using. Laravel 5.5 did not require guzzle itself, it recommended guzzle 6 though

Comment: how can i do for this issue?

Comment: Add this in your composer.json `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6"` (though I recommend to try with `^7` first) this should be under `require` then run `composer update` this should either resolve your problem or tell you which package is the one that requires the older version of guzzle (and probably needs upgrading itself).

Comment: Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/socialite 2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v2.0.0].
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, ..., 4.2.4] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6).

Comment: What actual version of socialite are you using? Socialite was working with guzzle 6 since version 2.0.5 and even version 3 of socialite supports Laravel 5.5 my guess is your socialite requirement in your composer json is wrong since even if you defined it as "^2" it would still get the latest version on the v2 branch and would have worked

Comment: yes. How to do it? Because i just new of laravel

Comment: "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "goodnesskay/laravelpdfviewer": "^1.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.5.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "2.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.37",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.9",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6"
    },

Comment: Use `"laravel/socialite": "^2.0"` instead of `"2.0"` and run `composer update`. In general it's not a good idea to use exact versions in your composer.json read about your options [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints)

Comment: now it got this error

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

Comment: now all solved. Thank you and love you so much